# Low coupling and SQL joins

Tags: database-design, orm, decoupling

Say I have a table `people (id, firstname, lastname)`.

There are two other tables that should contain these fields, so we'll just reuse the people table: `users (id, username, person_id)` and `companies (id, name, contact_person_id)`.

Now to get companies or users we must join the people table. If we change the people table, we must rewrite all queries, and probably lots of code.

Is this a real problem? Is my DB structure flawed? Is there a solution to maintain low coupling, like maybe ORM?

Thank you for all anwers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, the kind of modifications that would be made would not be disruptive, such as adding new columns. Breaking changes, like modifying column names or data types, is hardly ever done.

Relational database management systems allow the creating of special data types which make certain modifications much easer. If FirstName and LastName were defined as a user-defined type PersonName, then changing the type would make the same change appear in all the queries and stored procedures that use the columns. Unfortunately, hardly anyone ever uses user-defined data types.

If, conceptually, the thing called "Person" that is part of the things User and Company really represents a coherent idea, then changes to Person will not be disruptive, because any changes that are needed are needed everywhere. If, on the other hand, this is hacking conceptually dissimilar things together for convienience sake, then you are likely to encounter problems down the road.

Answer (score 4):

Coupling is a concept that is rooted in software modules.

I don't see the relevance to SQL.

Seeing as both tables live in the same server, they are already coupled (so far as the software using the server is concerned). I just don't see what low coupling you are trying to achieve.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29):

> In computer science, coupling or dependency is the degree to which each program module relies on each one of the other modules.

Comment: Yes, but can't it be applied to this? A User and Company object will both depend on the same table `people`. Or a Person object.

Comment: @Znarkus - Yes, but an object a _software_ construct. Both depend on your data access layer in order to retrieve the state of such objects. The dependency is on the data access layer, not how the data is stored in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Your foreign keys enable easy access to the data in the `people` table. Yes, it *may* require changes if the `people` table is changed, but changing something that affects your JOINs implies that your requirements have changed.

In other words, it is not realistic to need to change firstname, or lastname in a way that affects your JOINs. This is not a real problem.

What is represented above is the result of [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), which is common and good practice. By thinking of your tables as separate entities, as they very well may be in terms of logical relationships to the software, it does introduce coupling between tables, but it's by design to actually simplify and improve scalability.

This is good database design.

Answer (score 1):

> Now to get companies or users we must
>   join the people table. If we change
>   the people table, we must rewrite all
>   queries, and probably lots of code.
>
> Is this a real problem? Is my DB
>   structure flawed?

No, your structure isn't flawed in this context. Your perception of it is flawed.

Table names and column names make up part of the public interface to a database. Think of it as an API. No matter what kind of code you write, if you change an API, you're going to have to rewrite some code. If you change a database API--table and column names--you might have to rewrite a *lot* of code.  But  . . .

Let's say you check out your database code from your version control system, and you change the column names in your "people" table to first_name, last_name. Without any other changes, you won't be able to rebuild the database, because you've broken the public interface. (Views that select "firstname" will kill the build. Stored procedures that read or write to "firstname" will kill the build.)

But you can quickly recover from that by renaming the "people" table and creating a view. You might go forward like this.

- Rename "people" to "persons".
- Create a view named "people". (`SELECT * FROM persons;`)
- In the view, create aliases for the
  two changed columns, aliasing
  first_name to firstname, and
  last_name to lastname.
- If your dbms doesn't natively support
  updatable views, write whatever
  procedural code you need to make the
  view updatable.

Any code that expected to query or update a base table named "people" will instead be querying and updating a view named "people". No other code needs to be rewritten. (Unless you have code that makes unwarranted assumptions about whether it's operating against a base table.)

Relational databases implement logical data independence through updatable views.